# Is it a good to practice to have a long constructor in Java?

Tags: java

this is from a new to the domain!
thinking of an app to deal with an employee database in the university, an object employee should have at least 15 data points that need to be entered at object creation... is it normal to add all parameters in one constructor?

If no what are the alternatives?

Comment: For this type of scenarios it is recommended to use a Builder pattern.

Comment: Take a look at the builder pattern.

Comment: Hint: Builder Pattern

Comment: This is a question probably better asked on the Software Engineering SE, but typically when you have a large amount of parameters, you combine them into an struct/object and pass the struct/object as a parameter. EDIT: Apparently this is called the builder pattern. I learned a thing today.

Comment: It's seldom necessary.  Q: Where are you getting these data items from?  Q: Are you using an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), like [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/)?  If you *MUST* populate an object with many attributes, then - as others suggested - please look at the [Builder Design Pattern](https://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/creational/builder-pattern-in-java/)

Comment: @FoggyDay Yes I want to populate the object with manu attributes will take a look to the Builder Design Patter although I have some difficulties to understand it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Item 2 of *Effective Java, 3rd Edition* (Bloch) is:

> Consider a builder when faced with many constructor parameters

However, the introductory sentence to the item clarifies a subtle point: constructors with many *optional* parameters are especially bad.

> Static factories and constructors share a limitation: they do not scale well to large numbers of optional parameters.

In the text Bloch discusses two common alternatives to the Builder pattern:

- **Telescoping constructor pattern** (overloaded versions of the constructor with different configurations of the optional parameters);
- **The JavaBean pattern** (parameterless constructor and setter methods).

The long and short of it that the Builder pattern is preferred.